# Teradata SQL : Query a column for pattern that has spaces ( a.k.a a where clause to search for a pattern that has spaces, in a string )

Tags: sql, regex, database, teradata, sqlperformance

I can do this

```
where Col  like '%Mystring%String2%'
```

In Teradata SQL or  I can use the `?` for single char matches. How do I search for 
content pattern that is like this using Terdata SQL Regex 
  
`String<one of more instance of spaces or non alpha chars>string2`
e.g. 
`IS  NOT NULL` OR 
`IS        NOT NULL` 
There are 1 or more instances of spaces or some other Non alpha character in between 2 or more strings 
E.g. consider this string which is part of a `sqltext` in a `PDCR` database

```
sel t1.c1, t2.c2, t3.c3 from 
t1 , t2 ,t3
where t2.Cx is NULL and t3.cy IS NOT NULL and 
t3.Ca is         NULL          AND 
t3.cb is NULL AND          t3.c7 is        NOT NULL 
and t3.c10 not like  any ('%searchstring%','%string%','%||||%')
```

Note the varying amt of spaces between `NOT` and `NULL` and `IS` and `NULL`

So I wanted to form `where` clauses that'd check for various non alpha conditions like ( this is more pseudo-code like. sorry abt that )

```
 where Sqltext like '%NOT<1 or more instances of Spaces only>NULL%' 
    or SQLtext like  '%,\%<one or more instances of | character%' escape '\'
```

That was what I was looking for. `REGEXP_SIMILAR` seems promising. Trying to see how it can get long with a `where` clause

Comment: Some examples of data and desire result will help a lot to understand your question.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Define  *non alpha chars*, probably something like `REGEXP_SIMILAR(col, '.*?string[^a-z]+string2.*?', 'i')`

Comment: Thanks. I have given examples already. I am not looking for  here's the input and I want this output kind of answers.

Comment: Sorry, but your "examples" are confusing/hard to understand. *You* know what you want, but *we* don't.

Comment: Hi Juan and Dieter . Thank You both. Sorry if it sounded hazy Just edited and added more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex `\s` to look for whitespace (space, tab, CRLF):

```
WHERE REGEXP_SIMILAR(col,'.*?IS[\s|\|]+NOT.*?','i') = 1

.*?                    -- any characters
   IS                  -- 1st string
     [\s|\|]+          -- one or more whitespaces and/or | 
             NOT       -- 2nd string
                .*?'   -- any characters
```

Or REGEXP_INSTR, which is a bit shorter as you don't need the "any characters" at begin and end:

```
WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(x,'IS[\s|\|]+NOT',1,1,0,'i') > 0
```